# android gridview layout shrinks in the bottom of the screen when displayed on CRT TV

Tags: android, gridview

im trying to develop an android app that has a gridview in the main activity that will run on both regular screens and on old CRT TV.. (600X500 px for instance)..

when i try to run it on the emulator with such resolutions it seems fine.. and on computer screen it also ok,  but on tv it takes advatage only of the top 2/3 of the screen and the icons are cut and scrollable.. 
[image]

this is an illustration of what i see on the tv screen

relevant layout files:

```
<RelativeLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:background="#fffcfafa"
android:gravity="center_horizontal"
>

<GridView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
android:id="@+id/gridview"
android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:columnWidth="90dp"
android:numColumns="auto_fit"
android:verticalSpacing="20dp"
android:horizontalSpacing="20dp"
android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
android:gravity="center"
/>
```

manifest:

```
    <supports-screens android:resizeable="false"
    android:smallScreens="true" android:normalScreens="true"
    android:largeScreens="true" android:anyDensity="true" />
```

Comment: clicked post question too early.. now edited :)

Comment: try `android:resizeable="true"`

Comment: @Poovizhirajan.N answer the question i'll give u a vote... your tip solved me the problem with additional small changes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change support screens resizeable
from this

```
android:resizeable="false"
```

to this

```
android:resizeable="true"
```

hope it helps